# esri popupTemplate modify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arcgis, esri

How can i modify the popupTemplate in esri? is it possible for me to modify the popupTemplate according to my design?

I have a popupTemplate

```
    popupTemplate: {
      content: [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [{
          fieldName: "Name"
        }, {
          fieldName: "Owner"
        }, {
          fieldName: "Length"
        }]
      }]
    }
```

this is the result

[image]

what i want design

[image]

resource https://totalapis.github.io/sample-code/popup-custom-action/index.html

Update, I am having trouble on my react , when i clicked the icon there is no popup template show

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapDiv.current) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = process.env.ARCGIS_API;

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'arcgis-light-gray'
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        center: [123.5504, 12.3574], // Longitude, latitude
        container: mapDiv.current,
        map: map,
        zoom: 13, // Zoom level
      });
      view
        .when((r) => {})
        .then(() => {
          mapDiv.current = view;
          setMapView(view);
        });


        var list= [{
          type: "fields",
          fieldInfos: [{
            fieldName: "Name "
          }, {
            fieldName: "Owner"
          }, {
            fieldName: "Length"
          }]
        },
        {
          type: "text",
          text: "<div class=\"icontain\"></><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-star\"></i></a><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-geo-alt-fill\"></i></a></div>"
        }]
        var Stack= {
        content: list
        }
      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/Beverly%20Hills%20Trees%20By%20Block/FeatureServer/0",
       popupTemplate: Stack,
        outFields: ["*"]
      });
      map.add(featureLayer);
    }

    
  }, []);

  const displayLocation = (locations) => {
    mapView.center = [
      locations.data[0].geoCode.longitude,
      locations.data[0].geoCode.latitude,
    ];


  locations.data.map((location) => {
      const point = new Graphic({
        geometry: {
          latitude: location.geoCode.latitude,
          longitude: location.geoCode.longitude,
          type: 'point',
        },
        symbol: LocationPin,
        
      });
      mapView.graphics.add(point);
    });
  };

  return <div className="mapDiv layers" ref={mapDiv}></div>;
}
```

Comment: Is my explanation understandable?

Comment: @Usiel im going to apply first your answer, Im just having trouble applying your answer in my code

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: @Usiel, there is no popup happening in my code

Comment: can you please check my updated question @Usiel

Comment: Yes, I already saw an error - I do not omit this

Comment: where? can you please post your answer?

Comment: Share your code, where your first popup works

Comment: Thus, we can know why it stops working when combined with my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239993/discussion-between-kaito-and-usiel).

Comment: lets continue inside the chat

Comment: Check the update, if it works, just apply the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello**, a quick solution to modify the Popup template is to add another object with text and text type properties to the template array. the text value will be html code where we will create a div that will show the icons, these with their respective css classes. The most is CSS. Here is an example of the Popup template:

```
popupTemplate: {[{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [{
          fieldName: "Name "
        }, {
          fieldName: "Owner"
        }, {
          fieldName: "Length"
        }]
      },
      {
            type: "text",
            text: "<div class=\"icontain\"></><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-star\"></i></a><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-geo-alt-fill\"></i></a></div>"
          }]
}
```

I put an example of this code in operation already with the css, for a better compression. Your remaining task is to play with CSS to make the icon div responsive. For a better visualization of the example, run it in full screen. Another detail is that the example takes time to load due to the multiple CDNs that it needs

```js
require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer) {

      // Create the Map
      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
      });
      
      var view = new MapView({
        container: "mapDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-118.399400711028, 34.08713590709093],
        zoom: 16,
        // Since there are many elements, it is best to dock the popup so
        // the elements display better rather than have to scroll through them all.
        popup: {
          dockEnabled: true,
          dockOptions: {
            buttonEnabled: false,
            breakpoint: false
          }
        }
      });
      
      var list= [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [{
          fieldName: "Name "
        }, {
          fieldName: "Owner"
        }, {
          fieldName: "Length"
        }]
      },
      {
            type: "text",
            text: "<div class=\"icontain\"></><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-star\"></i></a><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-geo-alt-fill\"></i></a></div>"
          }]
      
      var Stack= {
      content: list
    }

      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/Beverly%20Hills%20Trees%20By%20Block/FeatureServer/0",
       popupTemplate: Stack,
        outFields: ["*"]
      });
      map.add(featureLayer);
    });
```

```css
html,
    body,
    #mapDiv {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .esri-popup__main-container{
      border: solid 1px gray;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .icontain{
     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: -17px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* margin-top: auto; */
    /* margin-bottom: auto; */
    /* align-items: center; */
    justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .ic{
      border: solid 1px gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
  /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>Multiple popup elements - 4.4</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/esri/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.4/"></script></head>

<body>
  <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

### Update

run this code in your environment. The popup should appear, you should only add the styles

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (mapDiv.current) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = process.env.ARCGIS_API_KEY;

      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'arcgis-light-gray', // Basemap layer service
        // portalItem:{
        //     id: "2d11c8164ce04843a38bfde68e00e6e7"
        // }
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        center: [123.5504, 12.3574], // Longitude, latitude
        container: mapDiv.current,
        map: map,
        zoom: 13, // Zoom level
      });
      view
        .when((r) => {})
        .then(() => {
          mapDiv.current = view;
          setMapView(view);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  const displayLocation = (locations) => {
    mapView.center = [
      locations.data[0].geoCode.longitude,
      locations.data[0].geoCode.latitude,
    ];




    locations.data.map((location) => {
      const point = new Graphic({
        geometry: {
          latitude: location.geoCode.latitude,
          longitude: location.geoCode.longitude,
          type: 'point',
        },
        symbol: LocationPin,
        popupTemplate: {
          title: "Sample",
      
          content: [{
            type: "fields",
            fieldInfos: [{
              fieldName: "Name"
            }, {
              fieldName: "Owner"
            }, {
              fieldName: "Length"
            }]
          },{
            type: "text",
            text: "<div class=\"icontain\"></><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-star\"></i></a><a class=\"ic\"><i class=\"bi bi-geo-alt-fill\"></i></a></div>"
          }]
        }
      });
      mapView.graphics.add(point);
    });
  };
```

### update css for button close

```
.esri-popup__header-buttons{
position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    left: -17px;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.esri-popup__button {
     z-index: 10;
}
```

try with this class and styles, to customize the close button

Comment: thanks, needs 14 hours to click the reward

Comment: How about to close button? i just want to move my close button in under the icon or circle

Comment: @Kaito Yes, I'll try.

Comment: thank you @Usiel

Comment: Update the answer and add css that to customize close button

Comment: the close button doesnt function properly

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239993/discussion-between-kaito-and-usiel

Comment: Where did you get that icon star?

Comment: The star icon is from [bootstrap icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)  `<i class="bi bi-star"></i>`